# Selection sort with reduced comparison count

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, sorting

This is an attempt to show how to use fewer comparisons in selection sorting a sequence of \$n\$ items than the \$(n²-n)/2\$ naive selection sort uses.

This is a first Python re-iteration of a [Java effort](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/174301/demonstrate-selection-sort-with-reduced-comparison-count), find the next at [Selection sort with reduced comparison count: Python iteration 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/175044/93149).

```
'''
selection sort implementations to show how to reduce
the number of comparisons (and input traversals).
Ideas:
- exploit finding min and max of n items in 3n/2 comparisons
- avoid repeating "input pair comparisons"

If and when indulging in (micro-)benchmarking,
  be sure to use an appropriate framework
  - and compare lemons to lemons.
'''

class Sorter:
    ''' In-place sorter. '''
    def sort(self):
        ''' sort items in place. '''
        raise NotImplementedError("Sorters better know how to sort");


class LoCoSelectionSorter(Sorter):
    ''' In-place selection sorter striving for a low comparison count. '''
    def getAssignments(self, items):
        raise NotImplementedError("LoCoSelectionSorters better know how to report the number of assignments");
    def getComparisons(self, items):
        raise NotImplementedError("LoCoSelectionSorters better know how to report the number of comparisons");


class TallyAssignments(LoCoSelectionSorter):
    def getAssignments(self, items):
        ''' assignments to <code>items</code>. '''
        return self.assignments;
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = items;
        self.assignments = 0;

    def trace(self):
        pass;
    def swap(self, i, j):
        if (i != j):
            items = self.items;
            items[j], items[i] = items[i], items[j];

    def prepare(self):
        ''' prepare iterations of <code>items</code>.
            return first index not to process "going upwards"
        '''
#           ? and destination index for the first max (after) ?
        raise NotImplementedError("TallyAssignments better know how to prepare iteration of items");

    def iteration(self, loDest, hiDest):
        ''' iterate (the unordered part of) <code>items</code> once. '''
        raise NotImplementedError("TallyAssignments better know how to iterate items");

    def put(self, dest, value):
        ''' put one value in <code>items</code>,
            keeping invariants as needed.
        '''
        self.items[dest] = value;
        self.assignments += 1;

    def put2(self, dest1, value1, dest2,  value2):
        ''' puts two values in <code>items</code>,
            keeping invariants as needed.
        '''
        self.items[dest1] = value1;
        self.items[dest2] = value2;
        self.assignments += 2;


    def sort(self):
        ''' Override In-place selection sort striving for a low comparison count.
            throws <code>NullPointerException</code>  if an element of a
                                        non-trivial array is </code>null</code>
        '''
        if not self.items or len(self.items) < 2:
            return;
        limit = self.prepare();
        self.trace(self);
        for up in range(limit):
            self.iteration(up);
            self.trace(self);

    #   ''' In-place selection sort striving for a low comparison count.
    #    * @throws <code>NullPointerException</code>  if an element of a
    #    *                non-trivial array is </code>null</code> '''
    #    public static TallyAssignments.Keeper sort(Comparable[]items) {
    #        TallyAssignments.Keeper sorter = new Keeper(items);
    #        sorter.sort();
    #        return sorter;
    #    }


class MinMax(TallyAssignments):
    ''' find both min and max in one traversal
        avoiding about one quarter of the naive comparisons.
    '''
    def __init__(self, items):
        super().__init__(items);
        self.comparisons = 0;

    def getComparisons(self, items):
        '''Override'''
    #    print((((self.last - 3) * (self.last - 1)) * 3) / 8 + 2*self.last+1);
        return self.comparisons;

    #@Override
    def prepare(self):
        '''Override'''
        last = self.last = len(self.items) - 1;
        if ((len(self.items) & 1) == 1):
        # for odd(length) arrays, find max and get it out of the way
        #  so only pairs need to be considered ever after
            maxI = max(range(last+1), key=lambda i: self.items[i])
            self.comparisons += last;
            self.swap(maxI, last);
            self.last -= 1;
        return len(self.items)//2;

    def minIMaxI(self, loDest, hiDest):
        '''find indices of minimum and maximum'''
        items = self.items;
        lo, hi = (loDest, loDest+1) if items[loDest] < items[loDest+1] \
            else (loDest+1, loDest);
        self.comparisons += 1;
        for up in range(loDest+2, hiDest, 2):
            if items[up] < items[up+1]:
                if items[up] < items[lo]:
                    lo = up;
                if items[hi] < items[up+1]:
                    hi = up+1;
            else:
                if items[up+1] < items[lo]:
                    lo = up+1;
                if items[hi] < items[up]:
                    hi = up;
#             self.comparisons += 3;
        self.comparisons += (3 * (hiDest - loDest - 1)) // 2;
        return lo, hi;


    def iteration(self, loDest):
        '''Override'''
        hiDest = self.last - loDest;
        lo, hi = self.minIMaxI(loDest, hiDest);
        items = self.items;

    # the tricky part is three elements moving
        if (lo == loDest): # min does not move
            if (hi != hiDest): # max moves
                ex = items[hi];
                self.put(hi, items[hiDest]);
                items[hiDest] = ex;
                self.assignments += 1;
            # else nothing moves
        else: # min moves
            mini = items[lo];
            if (hi == hiDest): # max stays in place
                self.put(lo, items[loDest]);
            else: # both move
                maxi = items[hi];
                if (lo == hiDest): # min comes from hiDest
                    if (hi != loDest): # max from in between
                        self.put(hi, items[loDest]);
                    # else min and max get exchanged
                else: # min from in between
                    if (hi == loDest): # max comes from loDest
                        self.put(lo, items[hiDest]);
                    else:
                        self.put2(lo, items[loDest], hi, items[hiDest]);
                items[hiDest] = maxi;
                self.assignments += 1;
            items[loDest] = mini;
            self.assignments += 1;


class Keeper(MinMax):
    ''' keeps pairs ordered to avoid about half the naive comparisons. '''

    def put(self, destination, value):
        ''' Override: order <code>value</code> conceptually at <code>destination</code>
            and the value at its "mirror-position" in <code>items</code>
            (such that the lower value is at the lower index).
        '''
        mirror = self.last - destination;
        if (#//destination == mirror ||
            (value < self.items[mirror]) == (destination < mirror)):
#             if destination != mirror:
            self.comparisons += 1;
            self.items[destination] = value;
            self.assignments += 1;
        else:
            self.comparisons += 1;
            self.items[destination] = self.items[mirror];
            self.items[mirror] = value;
            self.assignments += 2;


    def put2(self, dest1, val1, dest2, val2):
        ''' Override: order <code>value1</code> conceptually at <code>dest1</code>,
            <code>value2</code> conceptually at <code>dest2</code> and the
            values at their "mirror-positions" in <code>items</code>
            (have the lower value of each pair at the lower index).
        '''
        items = self.items;
        mirror = self.last - dest1;
        if mirror != dest2:
            self.put(dest1, val1);
            self.put(dest2, val2);
            return;

        if (val1 < val2) == (dest1 < dest2):
            items[dest1] = val1;
            items[dest2] = val2;
        else:
            items[dest1] = val2;
            items[dest2] = val1;

        self.comparisons += 1;
        self.assignments += 2;

    def prepare(self):
        ''' Override: prepare iterations of <code>items</code>.
            <br/>Resets <code>comparisons</code>.
            return first index not to process "going upwards"
        '''
        items = self.items;
        nItems = len(items);
        last = self.last = (nItems & ~1) - 1;
        middle = nItems//2;
    # place lower(higher) "buddies" at the lower(higher) index,
    #  never to be compared again unless at least one gets replaced.
        for up in range(middle):
        #   put(up, items[up]) # ?!
            u = items[up];
            d = items[last - up];
            if d < u:
                items[up] = d;
                items[last - up] = u;
                self.assignments += 1;
        # for odd(length) arrays, determine max and get it out of the way
        #  so only pairs need to be considered ever after
        if nItems & 1:
            maxI = max(range(middle, last+1), key=lambda i: self.items[i])
            self.comparisons = last;
            if maxI <= last:
                maxVal = items[maxI];
                self.put(maxI, items[last+1]);
                items[last+1] = maxVal;
        else:
            self.comparisons = middle;
    # when there are just two elements left, they are already ordered
        return middle - 1;

    def minIMaxI(self, loDest, hiDest):
        '''Override'''
        lo = loDest;
        hi = hiDest;
    # double ended traversal just makes this easier to read
    # - it may be easier on the memory hierarchy to do
    #  a single upwards traversal, switching from looking
    #  for min to looking for max in the middle
        for up in range(loDest, hiDest): ### XXX upper limit WRONG
            if items[up] < items[lo]:
                lo = up;
            if items[hi] < items[self.last-up]:
                hi = self.last-up;

        self.comparisons += hiDest - loDest;
        return [ lo, hi ];


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import random
    nItems = 18;#19
    items = [random.randint(10, 99) for r in range(nItems)];
    check = items[:];
    print(items);
    sorter = Keeper(items);
    sorter.trace = lambda sorter: print(sorter.items);
    sorter.sort();
    print(str(sorter.getComparisons(items)),
          " (", str(items == sorted(check)), ')', sep='');
```

I have never been a Python coder - it looks weird to me even when beautiful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the main code inside a function to avoid scope conflicts. In particular this will make it clear that you forgot `items = self.items` in `minIMaxI`.

The trace method is useless. You can easily insert prints into the source if you want to see this kind of thing, no need to provide a hook. In any case you've defined the default empty implementation wrong: if you remove `sorter.trace = lambda: ...` you'll see an error.

The abstract methods don't add much value. You can get rid of them.

`getAssignments` and `getComparisons` aren't useful.

Tracking assignments and comparisons yourself is tedious and error prone. In fact, I see that `swap` doesn't add to `assignments`, so you've missed some. You can track them automatically:

```
class AssignmentTrackingList(list):
    def __init__(self, it):
        super().__init__(it)
        self.assignments = 0

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super(AssignmentTrackingList, self).__setitem__(key, value)
        self.assignments += 1

...

items = AssignmentTrackingList([random.randint(10, 99) for r in range(nItems)])
...
print(items.assignments)
```

This also makes it very easy to swap back and forth between code that tracks assignments, and code that doesn't (which is faster).

Similarly, you can track comparisons of integers:

```
@functools.total_ordering
class ComparisonTracker:
    comparisons = 0

    def __lt__(self, other):
        ComparisonTracker.comparisons += 1
        return super().__lt__(other)

class ComparisonTrackingInt(ComparisonTracker, int):
    pass

...

items = [ComparisonTrackingInt(random.randint(10, 99)) for r in range(nItems)]
...
print(ComparisonTrackingInt.comparisons)
```

`str()` is redundant inside `print`.

You don't need the first check in `if not self.items or len(self.items) < 2:`.

Comment: `Put the main code` - did that about 80 mins ago after noticing one of the mistakes in `Keeper.minIMaxI`. There's another iteration in the makings…

Comment: (*not* a prompt to resolve this for me) `ComparisonTrackingInt` looks sane using `@functools.total_ordering`, but there seems to be an issue with `max(seq)` (which I might not have suspected without computing the count or keeping it with naked code)

Comment: total_ordering only fills in missing methods, so it doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Given (at least) one of `__eq__` and `__ne__` and one of the others, it does. So does using an open coded `max_index(iterable, low=0, high=-1)` - looking ugly…

Comment: @greybeard playing around with it I don't think it does. But I've edited to include a solution which does work.

Comment: `playing around with it I don't think it does` - where's *(at least) one of `__eq__` and `__ne__`*?

Comment: @greybeard See https://repl.it/KkTI/0

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this does look like a Java-structured program. Here are a few things to start with:

- remove `;` at the end of the lines, you don't need them in Python
- you don't need external parenthesis in the `if` or `elif` conditions. For instance, replace:

  ```
  if (lo == hiDest):
  ```

  with:

  ```
  if lo == hiDest:
  ```
- there is a [specific format for documentation strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) - use triple quotes, start with a capital letter and end with a dot
- improve your variable naming - first of all, in Python, it is agreed to name your variables and methods in a `lower_case_with_underscores` style. And, overall, make your variable and method names communicate what they mean and are used for - for instance, `put()`, `put2()`, `u` or  `d` are meaningless
- make sure to respect the current indentation level when adding comments - some of your comments are indented differently than the code they belong to
- you can make use of variable unpacking in some parts of the code, e.g. replacing:

  ```
  lo = loDest;
  hi = hiDest;
  ```

  with:

  ```
  lo, hi = loDest, hiDest
  ```
- look for other [`PEP8`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) code style violations like using spaces between operators, the use of blank lines

You can also run tools like `flake8` or `pylint` to perform static code analysis checks which would reveal the above and other code style and quality violations automatically.

Comment: `lo, hi = loDest, hiDest` doesn't seem like an improvement.