# Selection sort with reduced comparison count: Python iteration 2

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, sorting

Follow up to [Selection sort with reduced comparison count](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/174774/93149) - semi-final Iteration?
My goal (and excuse not to tag reinventing…) is to have presentable code to argue the viability of reducing the number of comparisons used by *selection sort* (for readers not necessarily versed in the implementation language chosen).
In this iteration, that is prominently `MinMax.iteration()` and from `Keeper` the methods `iteration`, `prepare`, `put` and `put2`, including intrusive comparison accounting for emphasis (and the possible addition of `MinMax.get_comparisons()` for computing the number of operations of interest).

Note to reviewers of previous iterations: finding suggestions not followed, be assured they were not ignored - feel free to chat (or flame) me, regardless.

```
'''
selection sort implementations to show how to reduce
 the number of comparisons (and input traversals).
Ideas:
- exploit finding min and max of n items in 3n/2 comparisons
- avoid repeating "input pair comparisons"

If and when indulging in (micro-)benchmarking,
  be sure to use an appropriate framework
  - and compare lemons to lemons.
'''
import logging

# demonstration code - you won't see production code for such
# - nobody rolls her own sort
# - for input where reduced comparisons do outweigh increased setup cost,
#   a sub-quadratic sort promises to do even better
#   - the related heap sort is "worst-case efficient"


# @functools.total_ordering didn't help, in the end:
# "composed" operators are "tracked" more than once
class ComparisonTracker:
    ''' call track() for each use of a comparison operator '''
    def track(self):
        pass  # logging.debug("useless tracker")
    def __lt__(self, other):
        self.track()
        return super().__lt__(other)
    def __le__(self, other):
        self.track()
        return super().__le__(other)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        self.track()
        return super().__eq__(other)
    def __ge__(self, other):
        self.track()
        return super().__ge__(other)
    def __gt__(self, other):
        self.track()
        return super().__gt__(other)
    def __ne__(self, other):
        self.track()
        return super().__ne__(other)


# "interface"
class Sorter:
    ''' In-place sorter. '''

    def sort(self):
        ''' Sort items in place. '''
        raise NotImplementedError("Sorters better know how to sort")


class LoCoSelectionSorter(Sorter):
    ''' In-place selection sorter striving for a low comparison count. '''

    def get_assignments(self, items):
        raise NotImplementedError("LoCoSelectionSorters better know how to "
            "report the number of assignments")

    def get_comparisons(self, items):
        raise NotImplementedError("LoCoSelectionSorters better know how to "
            "report the number of comparisons")


# This class used to be an abstraction of implementations
# - keeping an attribute "items"
# - "knowing" the number of "assignments" to items (#of __setitem__()-calls)
#   open coding keeping track thereof interfered with the purpose
#   "show how to reduce the number of comparisons"
# - provide for swap given two indices (ended up used up to once per sort)
# - define "sort" an operation of repeated "iteration"s from 0 to a "limit"
#   returned by a "prepare" step
#   (with a "trace" suitable after prepare() and each iteration())
# The name is preposterous with assignment accounting removed.
class TallyAssignments(LoCoSelectionSorter):
    def get_assignments(self, items):
        ''' Get number of assignments to self.items. '''
        return self.items.assignments

    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = items

    def value_at(self, i):
        ''' Return the (key value of the) item at i. '''
        return self.items[i]

    def trace(self, sor):
        pass

    def swap(self, i, j):
        if i != j:
            items = self.items
            items[j], items[i] = items[i], items[j]

    def prepare(self):
        ''' Prepare iterations of self.items
            returning first index not to process "going upwards"
        '''  # ? and destination index for the first max (after) ?
        raise NotImplementedError("TallyAssignments better know how to "
            "prepare iteration of items")

    def iteration(self, lo_dest):  # , hi_dest):
        ''' Iterate (the unordered part of) self.items once. '''
        raise NotImplementedError("TallyAssignments better know how to "
            "iterate items")

    def put(self, dest, value):
        ''' Put value in self.items replacing the one at dest,
            keeping invariants as needed.
        '''
        self.items[dest] = value

    def put2(self, dest1, value1, dest2, value2):
        ''' put two values in self.items
            replacing the ones at the destinations specified,
            keeping invariants as needed.
        '''
        self.put(dest1, value1)
        self.put(dest2, value2)


    def sort(self):
        ''' Override: In-place low comparison count selection sort. '''
        if not self.items or len(self.items) < 2:
            return
        limit = self.prepare()
        self.trace(self)
        for forward in range(limit):
            self.iteration(forward)
            self.trace(self)

    #    def order(items):
    #   ''' In-place low comparison count selection sort. '''
    #        sorter = Keeper(items)
    #        sorter.sort()
    #        return sorter


class MinMax(TallyAssignments):
    ''' Find both min and max in one traversal.

        Avoid about one quarter of the naive comparisons.
    '''

    def __init__(self, items):
        super().__init__(items)
        self.comparisons = 0

    def get_comparisons(self, items):
        '''Override.'''
        logging.debug("%d computed: %d", len(items),
            (((self.last - 3) * (self.last - 1)) * 3) / 8 + 2*self.last
            + (self.last if 1 & len(items) else -1))
#         logging.debug("counted by naked code: %d", self.comparisons)
#         logging.debug("overridden __setitem__: %d",
#                       ComparisonTrackingInt.comparisons)
        return ComparisonTrackingInt.comparisons


    def prepare(self):
        '''Override.'''
        n_items = len(self.items)
        last = self.last = n_items - 1
        if n_items & 1:
        # for odd(length) arrays, find max and get it out of the way
        #  so only pairs need to be considered ever after
#             max_index = max_index(self.items)[1]
            max_index = max(range(n_items), key=self.value_at)
            self.comparisons += last
            self.swap(max_index, last)
            self.last -= 1
        return len(self.items) // 2

    def min_max_indices(self, lo_dest, hi_dest):
        ''' Find indices of minimum and maximum. '''
        items = self.items
        start, beyond =              (lo_dest, lo_dest+1) if (items[lo_dest]
            < items[lo_dest+1]) else (lo_dest+1, lo_dest)
        self.comparisons += 1
        for forward in range(lo_dest+2, hi_dest, 2):
            if items[forward] < items[forward+1]:
                if items[forward] < items[start]:
                    start = forward
                if items[beyond] < items[forward+1]:
                    beyond = forward+1
            else:
                if items[forward+1] < items[start]:
                    start = forward+1
                if items[beyond] < items[forward]:
                    beyond = forward
#             self.comparisons += 3;
        self.comparisons += (3 * (hi_dest - lo_dest - 1)) // 2
        return start, beyond

    def iteration(self, lo_dest):
        '''Override.'''
        hi_dest = self.last - lo_dest
        lo, hi = self.min_max_indices(lo_dest, hi_dest)
        items = self.items
    # the tricky part is three elements moving
        if lo == lo_dest:  # min does not move
            if hi != hi_dest:  # max moves
                ex = items[hi]
                self.put(hi, items[hi_dest])
                items[hi_dest] = ex
            # else nothing moves
        else:  # min moves
            mini = items[lo]
            if lo == hi_dest:  # max stays in place
                self.put(lo, items[lo_dest])
            else:  # both move
                maxi = items[hi]
                if lo == hi_dest:  # min comes from hi_dest
                    if hi != lo_dest:  # max from in between
                        self.put(hi, items[lo_dest])
                    # else min and max get exchanged (never with Keeper)
                else:  # min from in between
                    if hi == lo_dest:  # max comes from lo_dest
                        self.put(lo, items[hi_dest])  # (never with Keeper)
                    else:
                        self.put2(lo, items[lo_dest], hi, items[hi_dest])
                items[hi_dest] = maxi
            items[lo_dest] = mini
        pass


# exact number of comparisons is data dependant
class Keeper(MinMax):
    ''' Keep pairs ordered to avoid about half the naive comparisons. '''

    def put(self, destination, value):
        ''' Override: order <code>value</code> conceptually at
            <code>destination</code> and the value at its
            "mirror-position" in self.items
            (such that the lower value is at the lower index).
        '''
        mirror = self.last - destination
    # destination == mirror  only with an odd number of unordered items
        if ((value < self.items[mirror]) == (destination < mirror)):
            self.items[destination] = value
        else:
            self.items[destination] = self.items[mirror]
            self.items[mirror] = value
        self.comparisons += 1

    def put2(self, dest1, val1, dest2, val2):
        ''' Override: order val1 conceptually at dest1, val2 conceptually at
            dest2 and the values at their "mirror-positions" in self.items
            (have the lower value of each pair at the lower index).

            dest1 shall be smaller than dest2.
        '''
        mirror = self.last - dest1
        if mirror != dest2:
            self.put(dest1, val1)
            self.put(dest2, val2)
            return
        items = self.items
        items[dest1], items[dest2] = (val1, val2) if val1 <= val2\
            else                     (val2, val1)
        self.comparisons += 1

    def prepare(self):
        ''' Override: prepare iterations of self.items.

        Return first index not to process "going upwards".
        Resets <code>comparisons</code>.
        '''  # and destination index for the first max (after)?
        items = self.items
        n_items = len(items)
        middle = n_items // 2
        last = self.last = middle * 2 - 1
    # place lower(higher) "buddies" at the lower(higher) index,
    #  never to be compared again unless at least one gets replaced.
        for forward in range(middle):
            #   put(forward, items[forward]) instead would at least
            # spare everyone discussing names u, d and outlasting this loop
            # (the catch being avoidable assignments)
            u = items[forward]
            d = items[last - forward]
            if d < u:
                items[forward] = d
                items[last - forward] = u
        # for odd(length) arrays, determine max and get it out of the way
        #  so only pairs need to be considered ever after
        if n_items & 1:
            max_index = max(range(middle, n_items), key=self.value_at)
            self.comparisons = last
            if max_index <= last:
                maxVal = items[max_index]
                self.put(max_index, items[last+1])
                items[last+1] = maxVal
        else:
            self.comparisons = middle
    # when there are just two elements left, they are already ordered
        return middle - 1

    def min_max_indices(self, lo_dest, hi_dest):
        '''Override.'''
        lo = lo_dest
        middle = len(self.items) // 2
        for forward in range(lo_dest+1, middle):
            if self.items[forward] < self.items[lo]:
                lo = forward
        hi = hi_dest
        for forward in range(middle, hi_dest):
            if self.items[hi] < self.items[forward]:
                hi = forward

        self.comparisons += hi_dest - lo_dest - 1
        return lo, hi


class PlainSelection(TallyAssignments):
    ''' Plain selection sort for reference. '''

    def prepare(self):
        return len(self.items)-2

    def iteration(self, lo_dest):
        self.swap(lo_dest, max(range(lo_dest, len(self.items)),
                               key=self.value_at))


# ToDo:
# comparison reduction along TAoCP 5.2.3 Ex. 8 (& combinations?)
# realistic heap sort for reference

# only miscellanea to follow
class ComparisonTrackingInt(ComparisonTracker, int):
    def track(self):
        ComparisonTrackingInt.comparisons += 1
    comparisons = 0


class AssignmentTrackingList(list):
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        super().__init__(iterable)
        self.assignments = 0

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
        self.assignments += 1


def main():  # to keep the global namespace clean
    import random
    nItems = 19  # 19
    items = AssignmentTrackingList(ComparisonTrackingInt(
        random.randint(10, 99)) for r in range(nItems))
    check = items[:]
    print(items  # , max(items)  # beware comparisons
          )
    sorter = Keeper(items)
    if 0 == len(logging.root.handlers):
        debug_level = getattr(logging, "DEBUG", None)
        logging.basicConfig(level=debug_level)
#     sorter.trace = lambda sor: logging.root.debug(sor.items)
    sorter.sort()
    print(sorter.get_comparisons(items),
          " (", items == sorted(check), ')', sep='')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

- Ideas to organise the code to make the parts mentioned as "prominent" in the introduction "eye-catching"?
- Additional ideas for reducing the number of comparisons in selection sort (short of mutating into hybrids with "well-known" sub-quadratic algorithms) welcome.